# Why do I get unmet dependencies errors when installing Nvidia 418 drivers on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, xorg, dependencies

I've setup the [proprietary graphics PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and run `apt update` successfully, but I get the following errors when attempting to install the Nvidia 418 drivers:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-418
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-418 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-418 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-418 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-418 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-418 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-418:i386 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-418:i386 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-418:i386 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-418:i386 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-418:i386 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The dependencies definitely exist, for example:

```
$ sudo apt-cache showpkg xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418
Package: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418
Versions: 
418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_graphics-drivers_ppa_ubuntu_dists_bionic_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_graphics-drivers_ppa_ubuntu_dists_bionic_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: a1eb1a42f08cae3b2102de9da0cd2b3b
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_graphics-drivers_ppa_ubuntu_dists_bionic_main_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: a1eb1a42f08cae3b2102de9da0cd2b3b


Reverse Depends: 
  nvidia-driver-418,xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1
Dependencies: 
418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 - libnvidia-cfg1-418 (5 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) xorg-video-abi-24 (16 (null)) xorg-video-abi-23 (16 (null)) xorg-video-abi-20 (16 (null)) xorg-video-abi-19 (16 (null)) xorg-video-abi-18 (16 (null)) xorg-video-abi-15 (16 (null)) xorg-video-abi-14 (16 (null)) xorg-video-abi-13 (16 (null)) xorg-video-abi-12 (16 (null)) xorg-video-abi-11 (16 (null)) xorg-video-abi-10 (16 (null)) xorg-video-abi-8 (16 (null)) xorg-video-abi-6.0 (0 (null)) xserver-xorg-core (18 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu2~) xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 (0 (null)) libc6 (2 2.2.5) 
Provides: 
418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 - xorg-driver-video (= ) xorg-driver-binary (= ) nvidia-driver-binary (= ) 
Reverse Provides:
```

Why doesn't apt install these dependencies automatically?

Comment: I'm using Bionic too, but I can't reproduce the error you mentioned, those nvidia package installed successfully in my side. What happens when you ran `sudo apt -f install` ?

Comment: Same result with apt -f install. I'm not surprised it doesn't reproduce; it smells like a local configuration issue, but I don't know what it could be.

Comment: I have recently had recurring timeouts while fetching GPG keys during the apt-add-repository run. A couple times I've had to manually import the keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be some sort of conflict between the `nvidia-driver-390` package that I had already installed. If I first remove the existing Nvidia driver package as follows, installation of the `nvida-driver-418` package proceeds without complaint:

```
$ sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-390 && sudo apt autoremove
```